# How do I highlight terrain around an object within certain radius?

Tags: unity

In my project, a player is not allowed to place forces in a given radius around enemy defensive forces. I would like to distinguish this area using some sort of highlight.

Second, I want calculate the radius for each enemy when the player placing forces clicks to check whether this player can put it there or not. Is there a more optimized way to do this other than looping through each character?

Comment: For the actual visual indication, I would use decals.

Comment: You have two distinct questions in here. I suggest you break it up and delete one of them and make it a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the highlight, you can use an Orthographic projector to project a round (or whichever) texture. The X and Z position of the projector will be the same as the enemy's X-Z position, and the Y position will be `terrain.size.y + 1`.